# SQL Server Group By UserID and Pivot By DateTime

Tags: sql-server-2012, pivot

Unlike the many similar questions, I haven't yet come across one like my requirement.

I need to report when users are logging on & off. This is the data in the table. UserID is unique.

| Logged | UserID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202103010657 | Peter | On |
| 202103010710 | Peter | Off |
| 202103011856 | Corey | On |
| 202103011904 | Corey | Off |
| 202103011206 | Peter | On |
| 202103011211 | Peter | Off |

I need to "pivot" it to be:

| User | Logged On | Logged Off |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 202103010657 | 202103010710 |
| Corey | 202103011856 | 202103011904 |
| Peter | 202103011206 | 202103011211 |

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `LEAD/LAG` here:

```sql
SELECT
    UserID AS [User],
    Logged AS [Logged On],
    NextLogged AS [Logged Off]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LEAD(CASE WHEN Status = 'Off' THEN Logged END) OVER
          (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY Logged) AS NextLogged
    FROM table
) t
WHERE t.Status = 'On'
```

Admnittedly, this will ignore cases when there are two `Off` statuses consecutively.